# Read The Docs CSS issue

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx

For some reason, my **custom.css** file has all of a sudden become unavailable when building HTML.

Under developer mode > network, I can see it in red, marked with an x, and with the following content-type status:
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8.

Upon investigation, I found that the value should be Content-Type: **text/css**; charset=utf-8 instead of **text/html**.

My conf.py is perfectly set and should trigger the right custom.css file.
Has this ever happened to anyone?

I went through the conf.py and custom.css files to see that there aren't any synatx typos.
I added docutils>=0.20.1 to my requirements file.

Comment: I'm confused; CSS files are generally served with the MIME type `text/css`, not `text/html`. Where are you finding that the value should be `text/html`?

Comment: The MIME type is a false lead, as 404s typically return a not found web page that is text/html. The problem is that the path to the CSS is not correct, but there is insufficient information to determine how to fix that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, thanks for replying.
What I meant was that instead of text/html, the value should be text/css. I fixed my question.